# WSGI Middleware recommendations

Tags: python, pylons, wsgi

I have heard that there is lots of interesting and useful WSGI middleware around. However, I am not sure which ones (apart from the ones that are part of pylons) are useful and stable.  What is your favourite WSGI middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSGI.org has a fairly comprehensive list of [WSGI Middleware & Utilities](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Middleware_and_Utilities).

Comment: This page no longer exists! I get a 404 Error! It seems to have migrated [here](http://www.wsgi.org/en/latest/libraries.html)